# How to set badge for UIBarButtonItem from Appdelegate (whenever push notification comes) if UITabbarcontroller is not the rootviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

How to set badge for UIBarButtonItem from Appdelegate (whenever push notification comes) if UITabbarcontroller is not the rootviewcontroller ?

I have a LoginViewController and a PinViewController before UITabbarcontroller. I'm setting LoginViewController as rootviewcontroller if user has not logged in and PinViewController as rootviewcontroller if user has already logged in. But I found that we could set badge for UIBarButtonItem from Appdelegate only if the rootviewcontroller is UITabbarcontroller.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by **Posting Notifications**

// In App Delegate Class

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSNumber *count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5]; // This is static...

    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:count
                                                         forKey:@"count"];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getPushNotification" object:dataDict];
    }
}
```

In Controller where you want to update badge count on bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateBadgeCount:)
                                                 name:@"getPushNotification"
                                               object:nil];

}


- (void)updateBadgeCount:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *theData = [note userInfo];
    if (theData != nil) {
        NSNumber *n = [theData objectForKey:@"count"];


        // Do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

Thanks.